How to group by all non-aggregate columns in select?
Is there some syntax in (Oracle) SQL that allows to group by all columns that are non-aggregate functions in select? I would like to avoid the code duplication in queries like the following (simple example, I frequently have 20+ columns / formulas duplicated in the group by)
select to_char(date, 'YYYY') as year, to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM') as month, product, source, count(*) as counts
from table
group by to_char(date, 'YYYY'), to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM'), product, source

I'm aware that with an outer select one can avoid at least the formulas in the group by, but it would be much simpler to have a syntax like
select to_char(date, 'YYYY') as year, to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM') as month, product, source, count(*) as counts
from table
group by all

with all meaning every column in select that is not an aggregate function. Does this exist in Oracle SQL? Does it exist in other SQL languages?

As you mention, you can wrap the query in an outer block and group only by the aliases. Or you can use analytic functions along with row_number and constrain on only the first row in a parent block, avoiding a group by clause altogether, but that's more code rather than less. I'm afraid there's unavoidably a lot of copy-paste in the world of SQL. It isn't a 3GL with the same goals as typical programming languages. It was, if I'm not mistaken, originally intended for non-developers/business users.

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language_generations it is 4GL :)

Oracle 23c syntax can't group all non-aggregated columns with one keyword, but it has two new syntax features that can at least help avoid some repetition.
Instead of repeating the expressions, column aliases can be used in the GROUP BY clause:
select to_char(date, 'YYYY') as year, to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM') as month, product, source, count(*) as counts
from table
group by year, month, product, source;

Or the expressions can be referenced by their position:
select to_char(date, 'YYYY') as year, to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM') as month, product, source, count(*) as counts
from table
group by 1,2,3,4;


Both year and month are key words, so you really shouldn't propose to use them as alias.

Nice! Too bad I'm still on 19c :(


Does this exist in Oracle SQL?

No

Does it exist in other SQL languages?

No.
In some languages (BigQuery and Databricks) you can use:
SELECT * EXCEPT (list_of_columns)
FROM   table_name;

However, those languages don't support using:
SELECT * EXCEPT (something),
       SUM(something)
FROM   table_name;
GROUP BY * EXCEPT (something)

So even when EXCEPT is supported it cannot be used to simplify your query.


Does this exist in Oracle SQL?

Nope, it doesn't (as far as I can tell).

Isn't it a pity? This syntax would save so much copy-paste time and would make codes so much more readable, easier to adjust and less prone to errors. How many times did I forget to add a new column in the group by...?

Certainly, I agree. But, in that case, it would be even better if we don't have GROUP BY clause at all and let the engine apply it internally, using all non-aggregated columns / expressions.
